# Simplest way to archive a Wordpress (and take down)?

Tags: archives

I want to take down a Wordpress site but save it somehow. Is there a way to archive it?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to save two things:

- Database.
- All files inside `wp-content`.

You can achieve this by the terminal or using a plugin like [All-in-One WP Migration](https://en-nz.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/).